# What is the valid syntax query for this?

Tags: mysql, syntax

I am trying to sum up a field if the condition field id is duplicate it will only be counted as 1 and app id is equal to 1.

```
   SELECT SUM(IF(PU.field_id IS DISTINCT AND PU.app_id =1,1,0)) as "With Reco" FROM tbl.PutUser.
```

I know for some this is just a piece of cake.

Comment: I think you should ask another question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Sample data and expected output would better illustrate what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the MySQL-specific `IF()` function,

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IF(pu.app_id=1,pu.field_id,NULL)) AS `With Reco`
   FROM mytable pu
```

or an equivalent, more ANSI standards compliant `CASE` expression

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN pu.app_id=1 THEN pu.field_id END)
```

to return NULL when the conditions we want to test aren't satisfied, and otherwise return the expression (`field_id`) we want to get a count of distinct values of when the conditions are met.  Then we can wrap expression in a `COUNT(DISTINCT )` aggregate.

For testing, drop the COUNT(DISTINCT ) aggregate, and return the individual rows...

```
SELECT pu.app_id
     , pu.field_id
     , IF(pu.app_id=1,pu.field_id,NULL) AS foo
  FROM mytable pu 
 ORDER BY ...
 LIMIT 80
```

That's my best understanding of what you are asking.

```
 app_id  field_id  foo 
 ------  --------  -----
 1       sam       sam
 0       sam       NULL
 1       sam       sam
 2       bob       NULL
 NULL    bugs      NULL
```

If that's not what you are asking, consider providing some sample data, and the expected output of your query.

Comment: perfect, exactly what I was lookinh for.